# How to add API data in react-native-multiple-select

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, picker

> I am very new in React Native and i want to add API data in
> react-native-multiple-select
> i want to add my post codes in multiple picker  which i get from API

```
import MultiSelect from 'react-native-multiple-select';

const [postcode, setPostcode] = useState([])
  const [data2, setData2] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchstateData = async () => {

      const responsepostal = await axios.post
        (`${urldemo}postal-codes`)
      setData2(responsepostal.data.result);

    }
  }, []);
```

> this is the response which i get from postcode API

```
[{"id": "postcode-0001", "text": "0200"}, {"id": "postcode-00010", "text": "2607"}]
```

> this is my return function for styling

```
<MultiSelect
                  hideTags
                  items={postcode}
                  // onSelectedItemsChange={onSelectedItemsChange}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                    setPostcode(itemValue)
                  }
                  // selectedItems={selectedItems}
                  selectedValue={postcode}
                  selectText="Post Code"
                  searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Post Code..."
                  altFontFamily="ProximaNova-Light"
                  tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
                  tagBorderColor="#CCC"
                  tagTextColor="#CCC"
                  selectedItemTextColor="black"
                  selectedItemIconColor="black"
                  itemTextColor="black"
                  displayKey="name"
                  searchInputStyle={{ color: 'black' }}
                  submitButtonColor="black"
                  submitButtonText="Submit"
                />
```

> my picker component which is working fine

```
<Picker style={GlobalSS.picker}

                  selectedValue={postcode}
                  mode='dropdown'
                  dropdownIconRippleColor='orange'
                  dropdownIconColor='#FF8025'
                  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                    setPostcode(itemValue)
                  }>
                  <Picker.Item color='grey'
                    label="Postal code" value="" />
                  {data2.map(item => (
                    <Picker.Item label={item.text} value={item.id} />
                  ))}
                </Picker>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck ? Are you getting the data from the api ?

Comment: yes i have the data from API
but in multiple picker it doesn't show me any postcodes

Comment: Then see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

regarding the library you are using , the documentation says that you should  pass an array of object following this structure

```
 const items = [{
    id: '92iijs7yta',
    name: 'Ondo'
  }, {
    id: 'a0s0a8ssbsd',
    name: 'Ogun'
  }, {
    id: '16hbajsabsd',
    name: 'Calabar'
  }, {
    id: 'nahs75a5sg',
    name: 'Lagos'
  }, {
    id: '667atsas',
    name: 'Maiduguri'
  }, {
    id: 'hsyasajs',
    name: 'Anambra'
  }, {
    id: 'djsjudksjd',
    name: 'Benue'
  }, {
    id: 'sdhyaysdj',
    name: 'Kaduna'
  }, {
    id: 'suudydjsjd',
    name: 'Abuja'
    }
];
```

> Each object must contain a name and unique identifier

So once you got your data from your api, I would map the result in order to format it in the right way.

In your case, it seems like you will just have to replace the field 'text' by 'name' like so :

```
  [
   {
    "id": "postcode-0001", 
    "name": "0200"
   }, 
   {
    "id": "postcode-00010", 
    "name": "2607"
   }
]
```

Comment: i have add this API to my other Picker component and its working fine but when i add in multi picker then it doesn't show me any of my post code

Comment: I have add my other picker component which is for post codes

Comment: I think your are passing the wrong data to the 'items' props of the Multiselect. You are passing 'postcode' and it should be 'data2'.

Comment: Plus, selectedValue props does not seem to exist in the doc. It should be selectedItems instead and it takes an array of string.

Comment: it works for me 
i also change this displayKey="name" to this  displayKey="text"